# Search a cell containing a string for characters that might indicate a date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to build some validation steps in Excel to support reveiw of data submitted as part of a template.

We want to check a free text cell for various criteria. One of which is to identify if the string entered in the cell may contain a date. In this case I'm assuming that the user could use any date format that occurs to them so I'm trying to simplify the check to something that is likely to be a date. Two patterns spring to mind where (if # indicate a numeric character) the cell contains either a `#/#` or a `#.#` pattern.

I can't use VBA in the check so this has to be done using formulae only.

I've tried SEARCH as `=SEARCH(c1, "#/#")` but the `#` character isn't a wildcard for a number in Excel (and I'm not sure there is one), but I can't assume that `?/?` is a date as that will return any / in the middle of the string.

In RegEx terms we are looking to match `([0-9]+\/[0-9]+)` or `([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)`.

Can anyone suggest a formula that would search a string to find either pattern?

I've added a table of example strings and the pattern we'd want to find to hopefully clarify what we're after.

| String | Matched pattern | Desired outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| In this cell there is no pattern to match to as the / and . characters do not have a number on both sides | N/A | FALSE |
| In this cell there is a pattern 1/3/22 that looks like a date but isn't a recognised date format | 1/3 | TRUE |
| In this cell there is a pattern 23.7.22 that looks like a date but isn't a recognised date format | 3.7 | TRUE |

Comment: There are so many variations I don't think there is an easy way to validate any and all possible date formats. Also is 01/02/2023 January 2nd or February 1st? You might be better off using data validation to restrict user input ni the template

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I've updated the question to hopefully make clearer what we are after. You are right and in one sense we are trying to not look for a specific date format here, only to flag up if the cell _might_ contain a date (not that it does for sure). Unfortunately we can't put a restrictor on this cell as it's a free text comment field.